# Matlab: Detect if spawning function is running (from within periodic timer function)

Tags: matlab, timer, countdowntimer

I want to create a function in MATLAB (2020) that displays a countdown in the console. Using e.g., periodic timers, this can be easily achieved (see below), however I cannot delete the timer when the user presses `CTRL+C` during the `pause(3.1)` (and the continued execution of `update_countdown` would lead to confusing results, deleting characters in the console instead of just displaying the update time)

Since timers seem to run asynchronously, my **idea is to detect whether the timer-spawning function `main()` is still running** or has been terminated - however I can't seem to find a way to detect this from within the periodic timer function `update_countdown`.

Based on my knowledge about figures that have

- a handle that can be detected as deleted and
- a `CloseRequestFcn()` - a function that can be specified to run *after* a figure has been closed,

I suspect something like this *ought to exist* for functions.

**(How) can I detect whether `main()` is currently running within my MATLAB processs** (from within the periodic timer function `update_countdown()`)?

```
%save as script and run
main

function main()
  timeout = 3;
  t1 = timer('ExecutionMode', 'singleShot', 'StartDelay', timeout, 'TimerFcn', @finish);
  t2 = timer('ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate','Period', 1, 'TimerFcn', {@update_countdown,datetime,timeout}); 
  %^datetime is a built-in function that passes the current time
  fprintf('countdown: %1i',timeout)
  start(t2); start(t1); %start timers
  pause(3.1); %<= arbitrary function 
  stop([t1 t2]); %stop timers
  delete([t1 t2]); %delete timers
  disp('Main: do more stuff!')
end


function update_countdown(src,ev,starttime,timeout) 
  %delete last displayed time, add new time (remaining)
  t=round(seconds(datetime-starttime)); % time running: current time - start time
  t=timeout - t;
  fprintf('\b%i',t); %delete last character and replace it with currently remaining time
end

function finish(src,ev)
  disp(' done!');
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function [`onCleanup`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/oncleanup.html) for this. It registers a function to call when the function exits (whether normally or through Ctrl-C). See also [this documentation page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/cleaning-up-when-the-function-completes.html).

```matlab
function main()
  timeout = 3;
  t1 = timer('ExecutionMode', 'singleShot', 'StartDelay', timeout, 'TimerFcn', @finish);
  t2 = timer('ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate','Period', 1, 'TimerFcn', {@update_countdown,datetime,timeout}); 
  %^datetime is a built-in function that passes the current time

  obj = onCleanup(@() delete([t1 t2])); %delete timers when function terminates

  fprintf('countdown: %1i',timeout)
  start(t2); start(t1); %start timers
  pause(3.1); %<= arbitrary function 
  stop([t1 t2]); %stop timers
  disp('Main: do more stuff!')
end
```

Comment: thanks I didn't find this function!  Tried to execute `stop([t1 t2])` AND `delete([t1 t1])`, but I couldn't get this to work using multiple function calls.

Comment: @user2305193: I don’t think you’d need to stop the timers before deleting them. But if you really must, you can create a separate function that you call, it doesn’t need to be an anonymous function. `function stopanddelete(t)...` and `onCleanup(&() stopanddelete([t1,t2]))`